# Find a minimum spanning tree using Prim's algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I have the adjacency matrix:
Where we have nodes a to g, and with their respective weights
x means symmetry, and the spaces left out are positive infinity

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c}& \text{d}& \text{e}& \text{f} & \text{g}\\ \hline
\text{a} & x & 7& &5\\ \hline
\text{b} & 7& x &8 &9&7 \\ \hline
\text{c} & &8&x&&5 \\ \hline
\text{d} &5&9&&x&15&6\\ \hline
\text{e} &&7&5&15&x&8&9 \\ \hline
\text{f} &&&&6&8&x&11\\ \hline
\text{g} &&&&&9&11&x\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

This is my attempt at prim's algorithm:

Initialization:

$u,v$ $List$

$-$   {a}

$(a,d)$ {a,d}

$(d,f)$ {a,d,f}

$(f,e)$ {a,d,e,f}

$(e,c)$ {a,c,d,e,f}

$(e,b)$ {a,b,c,d,e,f}

$(e,g)$ {a,b,c,d,e,f,g}

But I'm not sure about the minimum spanning tree, is this correct at all?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stick with your notation:

$(a,d)\ \{a,d\}$

$(d,f)\ \{a,d,f\}$

$(a,b)\ \{a,b,d,f\}$

$(b,e)\ \{a,b,d,e,f\}$

$(c,e)\ \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$

$(e,g)\ \{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}$

Making the total cost $5+6+7+7+5+9=39$. You went wrong in the third step, where you added $(f,e)$ instead of $(a,b)$.

NB: Draw it yourself, check that you understand each step and verify that it is correct :)

Comment: Hmm, why is the third one (a,b) instead of (f,e)? Isn't (f,e) the shortest path if you don't include nodes that already have been visited?

Comment: At that point you have only visited nodes $a,d,f$. So nodes $b$ and $e$ are (among others) unvisited. $\mathrm{cost}(f,e)=8$ and $\mathrm{cost}(a,b)=7$, so you add $(a,b)$, not $(f,e)$.

Comment: Thanks, also would I have to use curved lines to represent this MST when drawing it? Since say I'm drawing the nodes in order: a b c , then d e f g. a connects to d easily, but unless I use a curved line I can't connect to the bottom f (from d to f), since e is inbetween d and f.

Comment: I'd say you are completely free in how you choose to draw it. When solving, I drew the nodes $a,d,f,g,c,b$ clockwise, with node $e$ in the middle.

Comment: Cool, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you first draw the complete tree from the matrix then using Prim's algorithm you just add the egde with the lowest value to the minimum spanning tree and continue doing so until all vertices are connected to the minimum spanning tree (of course you should'nt add any edge if it doesn't add another vertice to the tree). I personally think that it is a lot easier to think about it this way

Comment: That's not what I'm so posed to do, these are the specific instructions I'm so posed to follow to get my answer.

Comment: I mean that you could do this to check your answer :)
It should give the same result